# What is the difference between python-boto3 and python2-boto3 rpms for fedora?

Tags: python, boto3, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I found that there are some rpms like python-boto3, python2-boto3 and python3-boto3. python3 rpm is understandable as python 3 compatible one. But what is the difference between python-boto3 and python2-boto3 ?

Comment: For fedora there is only [python-boto3](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/python-boto3). The other maybe for rhel or centos, or some other rpm-based distributions.

Comment: Where did you find them? Fedora now has a default of py3, so I can see a python2 version being needed (no suffix would be system default). Then RHEL7 is still default of py2, so a py3 version might be somewhere like EPEL.